table.putitem dynamodb running in for loop overwriting records
I am trying to add key value pairs in dyanmodb table for the same partitionKey. Here is the python code.
record_data = "orderId:569782152,incBaseFx:1.0"
record_data_list = record_data.split(",")

            for record_data_list_item in record_data_list:
                x, y = record_data_list_item.split(":")
                table.put_item(Item={
                    "pk": '787',
                    x: y

                })


After executing this code only incBaseFx = 1.0 is getting inserted in dyanamodb table. I wanted to see something like pk=786 orderId=569782152 incBaseFx=1.0

It's not clear what the primary key of your table is. PK seems to be the partition key with no obvious sort key.

If you intend to only have a single item that you append all values to, I would suggest using update_item as put_item will overwrite as intended. Furthermore, it would be more cost effective to build the item locally first, then call a single update_item.

If you intend to have a different item for each iteration in the loop, then be sure to have a sort key that makes that item unique.



You are updating 2 different key-value pairs in separated put_item API calls, this will cause the previously written key-value pair to be replaced with the new key-value pair. In order to retain the existing key-value pairs, you should use update_item API call instead
You can see this answer for more details on DynamoDB UpdateItem and PutItem APIs
